# How do I edit files on an SFTP server, connecting from Mac OS X?

Tags: tramp

At work I'm connecting to a server that only accepts SFTP connections.  I can connect from the command line just fine.  I'd like to use TRAMP or Ange-FTP or something similar from within Emacs, but I'm stuck.

When I say `C-x C-f /sftp:user@host:` I expect to get a prompt for a password but instead I get back `Unknown method "sftp"` in the echo area.

I'm using the TRAMP that came with Emacs, and I notice that `tramp-methods` does not contain anything for sftp.  Do I need to add something there?

Comment: Have you tried using `scp` instead of `sftp`?

Comment: Just tried. Saw "Tramp failed to connect. If this happens repeatedly, try `M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection`" in the echo area. Went to the `*Messages*` buffer and found the ssh command that was executing behind the scenes. Copy-pasted that into a terminal, got `PTY allocation request failed on channel 1` and `shell request failed on channel 1`

Comment: Sounds like the host has specifically disabled ssh access. The 'scp' method actually uses both ssh and scp to connect to the server (scp for transferring files, ssh for related tasks such as filename completion).

Comment: Have you tried using `scpx:` instead of `scp:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tramp supports `sftp` only in conjunction with gvfs. I fear, that this is not available for OS X.

Another possibility could be to use `psftp` from the PuTTY suite. Although PuTTY is dedicated to MS Windows machines, it might also be available for OS X. I know that it exists for GNU/Linux.